# How to add new slides to already exsiting JSSOR Slider?

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am trying to figure out how to add new slides to the JSSOR slider when its already initialized on a page?

Like, I have 10 images, and have the slider built for them. The thumbs show nicely and the slider is going smooth.

What I want to do is that, I add another 10 images dynamically using Javascript the the slides container. When I do this the slider wont show them. I need to know how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: For now, there is no API to add new slides after jssor slider initialized.